# Bash: find files within file size range and report their names to a file

Tags: bash

I would like to write a Bash script that selects files within a given folder with file size between 10kB and 100kB. This list of files should be written to a new file. Something like:

```
fileSelector ~/my-folder-containing-files ~/my-report-file
```

Can you help me develop such a script using bash?

Comment: Do you happen to have the code, and any issues you are having with it for review?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get a list of files within a specific size range, you can try:

```
$ find . -type f -size +10k -size -101k -exec ls {} \;
```

notice that since the size is calculated to be rounded up to the next unit, you would actually get a size range between `10241` to `102400` bytes from the above expression

if you want to make the limits to be byte-precise, you can use:

```
$ find . -type f -size +10239c -size -102401c -exec ls {} \;
```